# Deployment Issue in Weblogic 10.3 which targets to the Managed Server

Tags: java, weblogic

I am using Weblogic 10.3.I created a managed server along with machine.It is running well.
I try to deploy the application in weblogic I deployed which points to running managed Server but the deployment gets fails.
I am getting error has "" org/antlr/runtime/RecognitionException "".

Please help me to resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include the complete error from the log.

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/antlr/runtime/RecognitionException.

Comment: We need the whole stacktrace. From the look of it, the deployment does not have all the required classes. Please check your source code, weblogic.xml. You might be referring to antlr and it isn't there.

Comment: - <weblogic-web-app>
- <session-descriptor>
  <cookie-name>repsessionid</cookie-name> 
  </session-descriptor>
  </weblogic-web-app>

Comment: Hi Curious traveller this is my weblogic.xml

Comment: What I mean by stack trace is the whole error in the logs. "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/antlr/runtime/RecognitionException" will be at the end  of the line. the whole error followed by the stack trace is what I requested